# Proving thm. 22.37 in "Modern Classical Homotopy theory" by Jeffery Strom

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, group-cohomology, derived-functors

Here is the thm.

[image]

I want to prove it and I got a hint to use the universal coefficient theorem. I am confused about which statement of a universal coefficient theorem should I use and how. Here are the statements that I know on Wikipedia  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_coefficient_theorem for homology and cohomology. Also, I know this statement of the universal coefficient theorem from Harpreet Bedi lecture 8 called " homology to cohomology " in the homology series on youtube in this link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mvf8Pg26JLA&list=PL7BFF10190F42006E&index=8 : $$H^{p} (K; \mathbb{Z}) \cong Hom (H_{p}(K), \mathbb{Z}) \oplus Ext (H_{p-1}(K, \mathbb{Z}))$$

**I am guessing that the statement of Harpreet Bedi is the one that should be used but I do not know how this statement comes from the one on Wikipedia and how to use it to prove my theorem. Could anyone help me with this, please?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement from wikipedia is more precise, but here either statement is good enough for the result.

You just need to know what $\mathrm{Ext}^1_R($a free module,$R)$ is. This should be covered in any lecture about the universal coefficients theorem.

Comment: is the Ext of a free module and R is 0?

Comment: why are the 2 statements the same?

Comment: So I should use the one of cohomology from Wikipedia for proving the first isomorphism ... am I correct? what about the proof of the second isomorphism, How can I do it?

Comment: Yes to the first question. To the second question : they're not, the one from wikipedia is better and more precise. But the other one follows from it : if a short exact sequence $0\to A\to B \to C\to 0$ is split, then $B\cong A\oplus C$

Comment: The second isomorphism follows from the first one, because the double dual of a finitely generated free module is the free module itself

Comment: And why it is the double dual? does that because it contains homology and cohomology reversed?

Comment: How can we prove this double duality?

Comment: It's a general algebraic fact : for any finite $n$, $R^n \cong \hom_R(\hom_R(R^n,R),R)$. Try to prove it - in general, it's good to know the basics of linear algebra before trying to learn algebraic topology

Comment: Does this by using the natural mapping $J_{x}(T) = Tx$ for all T in the double dual of $X$? (assuming our space is called X)

Comment: So I should use the UCT for the proof of the first isomorphism and then the second isomorphism follows from the above mentioned linear algebra fact .... am I correct?

Comment: Yes (it's $T$ in the dual though, not in the double dual)

Comment: I think $T$ should be in the double dual

Comment: If $x\in X$, $Tx$ makes sense when $T$ is in the dual, not the double dual

Comment: My function is $ J: X \rightarrow X^{ ''} $ defined by $x \rightarrow J_{x}$ where $J_{x}(T) = Tx$ for all $T \in  X^{''}$

Comment: No : for $T\in X^*$, otherwise it does not make sense.

Comment: You are correct ... Thank you!

Comment: Can not we neglect using the UCT and use the above fact of linear algebra only in the proof? because my professor only mentioned the linear algebra fact and did not say anything about UCT while trying to prove it. He said UCT **or** the linear algebra fact and to prove that a diagram commutes

Comment: Not as far as I can tell, no. You need *some* input relating homology and cohomology